# finding the gradient, coordinate and area of triangle

Tags: coordinate-systems

line l1 has an equation  $$y=3x+2$$ and line l2 has an equation $$3x+2y-8=0$$.

- find the gradient of line l2.The point of intersection of l1 and l2 is P.
- find the co-ordinate of P.
- the line l1 and l2 cross the line $$y=1$$ at the points A and B respectively. Find the area of the triangle ABP.

I can't answer these questions help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the line l2 you can rearrange it and write in the form y=ax+b where a the gradient and b the y intercept. Thus, you obtain that the gradient of the line is `-2/3`. Equating now `l1` and `l2`: 3x+2=-3/2x+4, so `x=4/9` and `y=10/3`. Similarly you can find that `y=1` intersects `l1` at `x=-1/3` and l2 at `x=2`. Thus, the distance between these two points is `d=2+1/3=7/3`, which represents the base of the triangle. Its height can be found as 10/3-1 (the distance between the point of intersection of l1, l2 and the line `y=1`). Then apply Area = `(1/2)*Base*Height` to yield the Area. There are more direct ways of finding this area but they are more advanced from than the level of this question. It always helps to graph the lines though.

Comment: okay according to u what is the area of triangle ABP?

Comment: height = 10/3 - 1 = 7/3 base 2 - (-1/3) = 7/3. So Area= (1/2)*(7/3)*(7/3)= 49/18

Comment: okay thanks and i also wanted to ask when they say y=1 in this case x is always 0 right or x can be any value?

Comment: No, it is any real value. It is like stating: "We only care about y being equal to 1, x can be whatever it wants!" :)

Comment: thanks it really helps i like ur metjod

Answer (score 1):

- Try to bring line l2 in the form of l1, like y=ax+b, then b is your gradient.
- When you have line l2 in this form, try to set y=y and replace the left side with l1 and the right side with l2. You will eventually get a value for x (that is the x-coordinate of P). Put that x in one of the equations for the lines and you will get the y coordinate of P.
- Try to make a drawing first, then look at the formular for the area of a triangle and imagine a way to get the needed lengths for it

Comment: thanks using that I answered the first two questions  and my gradient for l2 is -3/2. The answer to the second question is (4/9,10/3) that's the co-ordinate now I can't find the answer to the third question please help me answer that

Comment: In the formular for the area, you need to know both the heigth and the length of the underlying side. Try to get the perpendicular on y=1 through P.

Comment: well I tried ny best I'm getting the area as 14/27 can u try to calculate your answer and tell me if I'm right or wrong and just let me know how u did it